# Shortcut to move one screen to the right/left in Excel

Tags: keyboard, ms-office

The official docs say to use `Option-Up/Down`

[image]

I tried that - as well as `Option-Left/Right` and `Command-(any arrow keys)` and they all do different things than the page right/left.

So is there any way to get this functionality short of point and click?

**Update** By playing around a bit more an answer was discovered:  the `Command-Left|Right Arrow` will page left/right ***to the next non-empty cell***. I had been seeing it page to the beginning/end since the particular rows had few entries.

***Hold on ..***  So the behavior is that the `Command-Left|Right Arrow will move to the next non-empty cell *if there were other intervening empty cells*.  So in the case of a row with all entries filled - e.g. the Header Row - a single invocation puts you at beginning/end of the *entire* row: so in *that* case it behaves like Row Home/Row End.

This is not acceptable behavior: is there any workaround?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it seems counter intuitive not to use the left/right arrows, (that is a subject for giving Microsoft some feedback) using the following key combinations work for **Excel 15.xx for Mac:**

---

#### Using Built-in MacBook Keyboard:

Page Right: <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>⌥ option</kbd>+<kbd>↓ down arrow</kbd>
Page Left: <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>⌥ option</kbd>+<kbd>↑ up arrow</kbd>

#### Using External Apple Wired Keyboard:

Page Right: <kbd>⌥ option</kbd>+<kbd>page down</kbd>
Page Left: <kbd>⌥ option</kbd>+<kbd>page up</kbd>

---

As noted in the OP's screenshot.